# Is it possible to restore a database from 10.50.4033 in 10.00.1600

Tags: sql-server, restore, migration

I did one project for my last year exam I want to restore a database.

Is it possible to restore a database from v10.50.4033 to 10.00.1600.

If yes, how is this possible.

Comment: Those versions don't make much sense given the tags, are you sure this is an Oracle database?

Comment: Erm, that's not an Oracle version number? SQL Server maybe?

Comment: Those do look like SQL Server versions. The 10.00.1600 one looks like SQL Server 2008 RTM and the 10.50.4033 is probably a SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 build.

Comment: Removed the Oracle tag, because those versions clearly aren't Oracle.

Answer (score 4):

Those look like MS SQL Server version numbers, not Oracle ones, `10.50.<patch_level>` and `10.00.<patch_level>` being 2008r2 and 2008 respectively.

2008 and 2008r2 are considered separate versions (much like 2008r2 and 2012) in most considerations including this one and backups are not backwardly compatible between versions, so no you can not directly restore a backup from 10.50.* on 10.00.* (though you can the other way around).

You will need to recreate the structure and then transfer the data.

If you have your structure in proper source control then remaking it should be easy, if not you can use the generate scripts function within SSMS and run the result on the older instance.

For the data there are numerous options and which will be suitable depends on may things, most importantly being can you connect to both database at once (in which case the data export/import in SSMS may be sufficient) and better still can they see each other over the network (in which case transferring using a linked server setup may be much more efficient). Listing every option available and their pros & cons would be time consuming (there are many sources out there that already do that), but if you update your question with further detail we can give more specific help.